# How to switch one activity to another activity using the Android Espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

How to switch one activity to another activity using the Android Espresso ?

I am using the android espresso framework for the test cases writing.

Comment: Currently I am in a activity but want to switch to another activity which is not navigational from the currently activity screen.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should consider launching another test for this new activity ?
Otherwise, using `Instrumentation.startActivitySync(Intent intent)` should do the work.